# errors with java on eclipse

Tags: java, joptionpane

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it? I'm running this on eclipse.

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.Icon;

public class JOptionPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // JOptionPane inputs
        Component parentComponent = null;
        Object message = "What do you think of Hudson?";
        String title = "VERY IMPORTANT!";
        String choice1 = "1";
        String choice2 = "2";
        String choice3 = "3";
        int optionType = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
        int messageType = JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE;
        Icon icon = null;

        // JOption pane display
        Object[] options = { choice1, choice2, choice3 };
        int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(parentComponent, message, title,
                optionType, messageType, icon, options, options[2]);

        // Switch
        switch (option) {
        case 0:
            //Button 1 result
            break;
        case 1:
            //Button 2 result
            break;
        default:
            //Button 3 result
            break;
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

The errors:
[image]

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: What makes you think you're doing something wrong or that your code needs fixing?  Is there some error you're getting that you haven't included in your question?  If so, please edit your question to add that information.

Comment: Both my option type and message type have errors when I try to run it in eclipse.

Comment: Don't give us an image of the errors, copy/paste them from your Eclipse console pane.

Comment: No need to mark the title as resolved - just [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) an answer instead

Comment: Sorry, This is my first time using the site. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class name is conflicting with `javax.swing.JOptionPane` - rename it to something else so you can import that class

Answer (score -1):

When need to asign a value use

```
int optionType = javax.swing.JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
```

Comment: The posted code still won't compile if the OP does that, due to the class name conflict with `javax.swing.JOptionPane`.

Comment: Even with the option type given a fully-qualified name, other lines (such as the call to `showOptionDialog()`) will still fail.  Fully qualifying all instances of `javax.swing.JOptionPane` is a very poor solution when this could be fixed **much** more cleanly by avoiding the name conflict to begin with.